Follow point by point a quintic polynomial
I am using ROS Noeticfor the first time, practically applying theoretical robotics concepts. I have to move the robot's TIAgo arm, following a quintic polynomial trajectory in Cartesian space.
From here, I can obtain the joint values for each point on the above trajectory, but I cannot understand how to pass each point to the robot to execute the trajectory.
My objective, in summary, would be as follows:

Obtain a Cartesian trajectory via a quintic polynomial (done)
Obtain the corresponding velocities of the joints using inverse kinematics (done)
Obtain the corresponding positions of the joints by integrating the velocities (done)
Tell the arm, at each time delta, that it must execute a point in the trajectory (NOT done)

Thanks in advance for your help!

When dealing with robots that have support for ROS, you'll need to search for the created controllers for them. I think this link about the trajectory_controller may be useful for you, where they explain how to send all the points that you want to reach in one Trajectory. You can also set the velocity at each waypoint.
